# Is yii model save() method secure?

Tags: security, yii, sql-injection

I have a model `User`
assuming i have created a new object from that model

```
$x = new User;
```

and set its property from a _POST var

```
$x->lastName = $_POST["last_name"];
```

if i did a

```
$x->save();
```

would it be secured from SQL injections ?

Thank you

Comment: Wow,  okay,  where is the code for this function?  Also,  why don't you just test it???  I don't think this is appropriate for SO.

Comment: the code is somewhere is a PHP Framework which will take hours to get , and when you're too close from a deadline you don't have even an hour to test SQL injections or to look for that code , moreover i am not that good in sql injection pen test as you are , thats why i asked this question to experts , and by being an expert you don't have to downvote a question just because you didnt understand it well .

Comment: it would take less time to test it your self.  It should take less than 1 minute to see if a single quote or double quote incurs an error.  You sir get a -1 for trusting SO instead of your own abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii uses PDO for connection, so yes, it would be safe from SQL injection.

But it is not safe from XSS. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/#hh11

Comment: its possible to use PDO improperly and still be vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$model->save()` the model's validation kicks in first, so your variables will be validated depending on the validation rules defined in the model, if there are errors then the model won't be saved, the values won't go into your db, hence no injection.

Validation rules are defined in the model's rules array, there are already many inbuilt validation classes, here's a [nice wiki article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) giving a primer to the validator classes.

You can also define [your own validators](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule).

So as long as you are *sanitizing* (or validating) your inputs you are good to go.